# If a topological space is separable are all discrete subspaces countable?

Tags: general-topology, separable-spaces

> Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space and $Y\subset X$ be such that $|Y|=|\mathbb{R}|$ and $(Y,\tau|_y)$ is a discrete space. Does it follow that $(X,\tau)$ is not separable?

What about the reciprocal, if $X$ is not separable can we always find a discrete uncountable subspace?

Comment: I found an answer to my main question
[here.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/391168/is-uncountable-subset-of-separable-space-separable?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\Psi$ be maximal family of almost disjoint subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ that has cardinality continuu. Consider the associated [Mrówka space](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/462029/17929) $X_\Psi = \mathbb{N} \cup \Psi$. Then $\Psi$ is a discrete subspace and $X_\Psi$ is separable because $\mathbb{N}$ is dense in it.